# socket programming in tcl problems

Tags: sockets, tcl

I have created this client program in itcl to interact with python server. My problem is that when I run this client sometimes it receives response from the server and sometimes not. while not receiving response ,even it is not producing any error. There is no error at server side.

Is there any error in creating socket? Please help me.

```
package require itcl
package require json
package require ncgi
namespace import ::itcl::*
class StaffSocketClient123 {

    variable clientSocket
    constructor {port} {
        set host localhost
        set clientSocket [socket $host $port]
        fconfigure $clientSocket -buffering line
    }

    method send_message {message} {
        #fconfigure $clientSocket -buffering line 

        set jsonMessage [json::dict2json $message]
        set stringMessage [format "%s" $jsonMessage]
        puts "request is: $stringMessage"
        puts $clientSocket $stringMessage

        set replyFromServer [ncgi::decode [gets $clientSocket]]
        puts " Response from server : $replyFromServer"
        #set intermediateReply $replyFromServer
        set resultInDict [json::json2dict $replyFromServer]
        puts "from server in dict format:  $resultInDict"

        return $resultInDict
    }

    method create_component {varrequest_type varcommand varcomponent_type varhost varrequest_timeout varport} {
        set message [dict create request_type $varrequest_type command $varcommand params [dict create component_type $varcomponent_type host $varhost request_timeout $varrequest_timeout port $varport]]
        puts "request in dictionary format: $message"
        set response [send_message $message]
        set component_id [dict get $response component_id]
        #puts "component id: $component_id"
        return $component_id              
    }

    method perform_action {varrequest_type varcommand varcomponent_id varurl} {
        set message [dict create request_type $varrequest_type command $varcommand params [dict create component_id $varcomponent_id url $varurl]]

        puts "Action message is: $message"
        set response [send_message $message]
        return $response
    }
}

StaffSocketClient123 ssc 9999
set component_id "[ssc create_component action create_component WebComponent localhost 5 9999]"
```

Comment: You should try logging the raw responses from the server (i.e., what you get back from the `gets` before you `ncgi::decode` it). That might help…

Comment: I don't see `fileevent` or `vwait` -- how does it listen for events?

Comment: @glennjackman Looks like its synchronous client-side code.

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing the client after puts or configuring buffering differently.  So :

```
puts $sock "message"
flush $sock
```

Comment: Thanks! its working now but i have added one more thing in fconfigure command: fconfigure -buffering full -buffesize 4096